# jQuery slideToggle creates hidden or visible elements?

Tags: jquery, filter

I'm using a button to slideToggle the display of my disclaimer here, and for some reason, I cannot find out how to change the value of the button properly.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('<input type="button" id="toggleButton" value="Hide">')
    .insertAfter('#disclaimer')
    .click(function() {
  $(this).prev().slideToggle('slow');

  if($(this).prev().is(':visible')) {
    $(this).val('Hide');
  } else {
    $(this).val('Show');
  }

  });

});
```

So, I believe everything is in order except for the

```
.is(':visible')
```

portion.  Now, I'm wondering if because when the disclaimer is toggled, although it appears hidden, according to jQuery, it is only toggled not *hidden* so I need to change the

```
:visible
```

filter to a different one.

Any suggestions for filter or anything else?  Also, I already know my this and .prev() references are functioning properly, because the slideToggle occurs, the button's value however, does not.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Figure the HTML for my test page would be useful:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <title>StarTrackr!</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/base.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />  

  <script src="../../lib/jquery-1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="header">
      <h1>StarTrackr!</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <h2>
        Welcome!
      </h2>
      <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Buy Now!</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Gift Ideas</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <p id="intro">
        Welcome to <strong>StarTrackr!</strong> the planet's premier celebrity tracking and monitoring service. Need to know where in the world the best bands, musicians or producers are within 2.2 square meters? You've come to the right place. We have a very special special on B-grade celebs this week, so hurry in!    
      </p>
      <p id="disclaimer">
        Disclaimer! This service is not intended for the those with criminal intent. Celebrities are kind of like people so their privacy should be respected.
      </p>

      <div id="news">
        <h2>Latest News</h2>
        <p>
          Which member of the seminal calypso/lectro band <em>C&amp;C Music Sweatshop</em> was spotted last night at <em>Dirt</em>, the trendy New York restaurant that serves only food caught and retrieved by the chef's own hands?
          <span class="spoiler">Yes! It's the ever-effervescent, <em>Glendatronix</em>!</span>
        </p>
        <p>Who lost their recording contract today? <span class="spoiler">The Zaxntines!</span></p>
      </div>
      <div id="celebs">
        <h2 class="heading">Our Celebrities</h2>
        <p class="info">
          We have an ever changing roster of newly chipped celebrities. But it can take as little as a week for the little critters to realise they've been tagged - so you have to be fast! 
        </p>
        <table class="data">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Occupation</th>
              <th>Approx. Location</th>
              <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>203A</td>
              <td>Johny Stardust (<a href="bio.pdf">bio</a>)</td>
              <td>Front-man</td>
              <td>Los Angeles</td>
              <td>$39.95</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>141B</td>
              <td>Beau Dandy (<a href="img.jpg">pic</a>,<a href="bio.pdf">bio</a>)</td>
              <td>Singer</td>
              <td>New York</td>
              <td>$39.95</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>2031</td>
              <td>Mo' Fat (<a href="img.jpg">pic</a>)</td>
              <td>Producer</td>
              <td>New York</td>
              <td>$19.95</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>007F</td>
              <td>Kellie Kelly (<a href="bio.pdf">bio</a>,<a href="w.doc">press</a>)</td>
              <td>Singer</td>
              <td>Omaha</td>
              <td>$11.95</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>8A05</td>
              <td>Darth Fader (<a href="img.jpg">pic</a>)</td>
              <td>DJ</td>
              <td>London</td>
              <td>$19.95</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>6636</td>
              <td>Glendatronix  (<a href="bio.pdf">bio</a>,<a href="w.doc">press</a>)</td>
              <td>Keytarist</td>
              <td>London</td>
              <td>$39.95</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>


      <div id="comment">
        <h2>Leave a comment</h2>
        name:<br />
        <input type="text" /><br/>
        comment:<br/>
        <textarea rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
      </div>

      <h2>Fine Print</h2>
      <p id="fine_print">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.    
      </p>

    </div>

    <div id="footer">
      <p>
        &copy; Copyright 2010 CelebriTracker Productions
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaScript function is marching on instead of waiting for slideToggle to finish so you'll need to stick your test in the callback for the animation:

```
$('<input type="button" id="toggleButton" value="Hide">')
    .insertAfter('#disclaimer')
    .click(function() {
        $(this).prev().slideToggle('slow', function() { 

            if($('#disclaimer').is(':visible')) {
                $('#toggleButton').val('Hide');
            } else {
                $('#toggleButton').val('Show');
            }

        });

    });
```

Comment: Hey thanks, that did it!  Also, just to clarify because I'm still a n00b:  When you mean the JS function was marching on, you're saying that the if else statement wouldn't work without placing it in the callback for the animation because why?  Even if it's marching on, wouldn't you be able to check if the #disclaimer is visible or not?

Comment: I don't think it's a n00b question at all: it doesn't really make sense to me either. As far as I can tell, jQuery isn't bothering to check the actual visibility of the element. Someone mentions it in the comments at the bottom of the 'visibility' selector page: http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/ Maybe it's checking the 'animated' selector and then not bothering with it?

Comment: Hey nice!  I see the comment, and that makes sense then to place the if else statement as a callback function of the slideToggle, because animated elements will be shown as visible until the animation has finished.  Thanks!